# Are plate-loaded vest comfortable for push-up/plank/dip/pull-up?

Tags: bodybuilding, bodyweight-exercises, weights, calisthenics, resistancetraining

do you think this kind of product is comfortable for weighted push-ups/planks?

[image]

I'm interested at buying it. Do you think it is a valid way to progress those exercises? My doubt is if it is comfortable to hold on the upper traps, and if it will be an obstacle to scapular movement.

In case it is adequate, I could utilize it also for pull-ups and dips, although a classical belt may be more comfortable in such cases.

Do you think it is a valid equipment for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As someone with a boney hip, using the weight belts always cause me such discomfort. Using one of these vests would be a great alternative to people like me who experience pain from belts.

Concerning your question on scapular movement, I can't imagine the vest hindering your form (if your form is good to begin with). However, since the weight slot is on the front of the jacket, adding a few plates may end up pulling the jacket too far forward and hence squishing your lats and restricting some movement.

I've experienced this with lifting straps that velcro all the way around my wrists; they're super convenient for low weight, but as the weight goes up it starts cause issues.

All in all, I think this piece of equipment would serve to be useful if you aren't loading it up with a lot of weight (a 45lb weight or less). Otherwise, you may see some issues with scapular movement.

Hope this helped!